# Saltstack copy files with specific extension

Tags: salt-stack

I need to install specific rpm file which I'm pulling from git and it looks like this "zabbix-agent2-5.2.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm"

This is state file which I'm using:

```
install_pkg:
  pkg.installed:
    - sources:
      - zabbix_agen2: salt://some/path/zabbix-agent2-5.2.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

**The question is, is there any option to specify dynamic file name?**

Something like `salt://some/path/zabbix-agent2*.rpm`

Because in this moment I have to rename file in source directory for something like zabbix-agent2.rpm but I'd like to have that version in it's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sources` parameter takes an absolute filename, and doesn't consider wildcards. This is where [pillar](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/getstarted/config/pillar.html) can be used to dynamically supply the version (at runtime).

For example:

```yaml
install_pkg:
  pkg.installed:
    - sources:
      - zabbix_agen2: salt://some/path/zabbix-agent{{ pillar['zabbix_version'] }}.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Pillar values can be supplied from an SLS file in the pillar, or it can be passed when running the state file, like:

```
salt myminion state.apply mypkg pillar='{"zabbix_version": "2-5.2.4-1"}'
```

Here we run the `mypkg` state on `myminion` by supplying the version of the package that we would like to install.